# Export to CSV file

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, csv

I am able to read the SharePoint web part properties and values using below code and able to export it. But after exporting, when i open the file could not find exact values.

Find the code below:

```
$userId = ""  
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd)  
$ctx.credentials = $creds   
#Not required for on premise site - End

#page to be viewed  
$pageName = "TestPage1.aspx"  
#Get the page  
$file = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Pages/TestPage1.aspx")  
$ctx.Load($file)  
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get all the webparts  
Write-Host "Retrieving webparts"  
$wpManager = $file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)  
$webparts = $wpManager.Webparts  
$ctx.Load($webparts)  
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()



if($webparts.Count -gt 0){  
    Write-Host "Looping through all webparts"  
    foreach($webpart in $webparts){  
        $ctx.Load($webpart.WebPart.Properties)  
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
        $propValues = $webpart.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues  
        Write-Host "ID: $webpart.id"  
        foreach($property in $propValues){  
            Write-Host "Title: " $property.Title                  
            Write-Host "Description: " $property.Description  
            Write-Host "Chrome Type: " $property.ChromeType 

        $listItemData = @{
            "Webpart Title" = $property.Title
            "Webpart Description" = $property.Description
            "Chrome Type" = $property.ChromeType 
            }
           New-Object PSObject -Property $listItemData

        }  

    }  
}  

$listItemData |Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "Your CSV file path"
```

Output of code:

```
Webpart Title           Chrome Type Webpart Description
-------------           ----------- -------------------
Web Part Page Title Bar           2
Content Editor                    0 Allows authors to enter rich text content.
Script Editor                     2 Allows authors to insert HTML snippets or scripts.
Image Viewer                      0 Displays a specified image.
```

Exported CSV:

[image]

why i am not able to get the output values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code and it works fine now.

```
$siteURL="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"
$userId = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"  
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd)  
$ctx.credentials = $creds   
#Not required for on premise site - End

#page to be viewed  
$pageName = "TestPage1.aspx"  
#Get the page  
$file = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/SitePages/webpartpage.aspx")  
$ctx.Load($file)  
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get all the webparts  
Write-Host "Retrieving webparts"  
$wpManager = $file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)  
$webparts = $wpManager.Webparts  
$ctx.Load($webparts)  
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


$listItemData=@()
if($webparts.Count -gt 0){  
    Write-Host "Looping through all webparts"  
    foreach($webpart in $webparts){  
        $ctx.Load($webpart.WebPart.Properties)  
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
        $propValues = $webpart.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues  
        Write-Host "ID: $webpart.id"  
        foreach($property in $propValues){  
            Write-Host "Title: " $property.Title                  
            Write-Host "Description: " $property.Description  
            Write-Host "Chrome Type: " $property.ChromeType 

        $listItemData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                "Webpart Title" = $property.Title
"Webpart Description" = $property.Description                
"Chrome Type" = $property.ChromeType                                                             
            }


        }  

    }  
}  

$listItemData |Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\\Temp\\test.csv"
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code this way - it is working fine.

```
Function GetWebPartPropertyDetails()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SPOSiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $pageRelativeURL,        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $UserName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Password
    )

    Try 
    {      

        $securePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
        #Setup the Context
        $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOSiteURL)
        $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $securePassword)

        $fileByServerRelativeUrl=$pageRelativeURL

        #Getting the page details
        $file = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($fileByServerRelativeUrl)  
        $ctx.Load($file)  
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


       #Extract all the webparts from the given page.  
        Write-Host "Extracting all webparts from the given page."  
        $wpManager = $file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)  
        $webpartColls = $wpManager.Webparts  
        $ctx.Load($webpartColls)  
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  

        if($webpartColls.Count -gt 0)
        {  
        Write-Host "Looping through all webparts in the page."

        $webPartCount=1   
        foreach($oneWebpart in $webpartColls)
        {  
            $ctx.Load($oneWebpart.WebPart.Properties)  
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
            $wpPropValues = $oneWebpart.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues  
            Write-Host "Webpart ID: " $oneWebpart.ID

            Write-Host $webPartCount

            Write-Host "##########################" -f Green

            foreach($oneProperty in $wpPropValues)
            {  



                Write-Host "Title: " $oneProperty.Title                  
                Write-Host "Description: " $oneProperty.Description  
                Write-Host "Chrome Type: " $oneProperty.ChromeType
                Write-Host "Back Ground Color: "$oneProperty.BackgroundColor
                Write-Host "Allow Edit: "$oneProperty.AllowEdit
                Write-Host "Allow Hide: "$oneProperty.AllowHide


                $listItemData = @{
                "Webpart Title" = $oneProperty.Title
                "Webpart Description" = $oneProperty.Description
                "Chrome Type" = $oneProperty.ChromeType 
                "Allow Edit" = $oneProperty.AllowEdit
                "Allow Hide" = $oneProperty.AllowHide
               }

                New-Object PSObject -Property $listItemData

            }


            Write-Host "##########################" -f Green  
            $webPartCount++  


        }  

    }  

     Write-host -f Green "The web part details successfully have been extracted."
    }
    Catch 
    {

            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in reading web part properties!:" 
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

    }

    return $listItemData
}
```

**Call the above function like below:**

```
#Parameters value
$siteURL="Your site URL"

$PageRelativeURL="/sites/yoursite/SitePages/your_webpart_page.aspx"     
$userName = "Your username"
$passWord = "Your Password"
#Parameters ends here.

#Calling the GetWebPartPropertyDetail function and passing the parameters.
GetWebPartPropertyDetails $siteURL $PageRelativeURL $userName $passWord | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\TestExport.csv"
```

**Output**:

[image: Export webpart details to CSV file]